# How to use the HORI Real Arcade Pro EX stick for Xbox 360 in WinKawaks?

Tags: controllers, windows-7, emulation

Currently I got my hands on the WinKawaks, and tried to hook up the HRAP EX stick on my computer, after done some homework on Google, I found [this link on shoryuken forum](http://shoryuken.com/forum/index.php?threads/how-to-make-the-hori-fightingstick-ex2-work-on-windows.31858/), I followed the route there and installed the XBCD, and the stick is properly listed as HRAP EX in my Windows device manager, also the pressing of the buttons can be correctly registered in the gaming controller configuration.

However in WinKawaks, the 7(up-left) is constantly registered as input, in KOF99, the character I control would always jump to the left end of the arena once the fight begins, I wonder is this a problem with WinKawaks not being able to use the correct driver? or there is a problem with the driver itself? Has anyone successfully use HRAP EX stick in an emulator?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these (I've only configured a MadCatz stick on a Mac), but the XBox 360 analog sticks send an axis coordinate for the driver. Perhaps your driver doesn't have the axis correctly configured and the 7 is always in the range. Can you change which stick is mapped to the controller, as in the MadCatz sticks? If you can, you could try changing it to the D-pad, which is a digital input.

Comment: Pro tip: never suggest closing to the mods on any stackexchange site! There are always half a dozen or so who are genuinely obsessive about "question purity" and are more than willing to close perfectly legitimate questions for no good reason, so don't tempt them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If winkawaks seems to be the problem, try using the free version of xpadder (see link in this question: [How can I emulate keyboard and mouse commands with a game controller?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13575) ) instead:

Get xpadder configured to translate the stick movements and buttons to key presses (there are probably profiles already out there for the HRAP EX, try google). Then configure those keys in winkawaks.

As a bonus, you'll be able to use the HRAP EX in any other game, too.