# Using the Mayflash GameCube to USB adapter. All buttons work except the C-Stick?

Tags: pc, controllers, emulation

I got a Mayflash "GC Controller Adapter for PC USB".  I plugged the GC controller into Port 1 on the Mayflash adapter (it's a dual-port) and plugged the adapter into the USB on my computer.  I noticed that programs on my computer weren't really recognizing my controller that was hooked in, so I got a free program called "JoyToKey" that accepts inputs from a controller and sets the input to a certain key on the keyboard.  JoyToKey works perfectly with the controller, but the only command that does not function properly is the C-Stick.  If I program a key, say the letter "U" for example, to Left on the C-Stick, it seems to register all along the top of the C-Stick, but not the left.  In other words, if I push the C-Stick up-left, up, up-right, or right, JoyToKey registers the input, even though I set it to only register when I push the C-Stick left.

I have tried calibrating the controls via the Windows USB Game Controller setup, but it does not work (using Windows 8 64-bit by the way).  What can I do to fix this?  If you need any more details or examples, I will post them, just let me know what you need.  Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:  I don't have a way of truly knowing if the issue is JoyToKey or just Windows, but in the Windows USB controller setup, the C-Stick corresponds to the Z-Axis, and it seems to be working okay.  If I can find out how the Z-Axis is supposed to register then I might be able to fix the problem.

Comment: Is there a way you can determine if this is an issue with the Adapter or the "JoyToKey" Software?  Perhaps a game that has controller support or something which the "JoyToKey" is not running?

Comment: If you have the [Mayflash PC051]( onehttp://www.mayflash.com/Products/PCUSB/PC051.html), does it support windows 8? does it support rumble? Do wavebirds work?

Comment: That is the model I have.  It said on the package that it supported Windows 8 32-bit and 64-bit.  It does support rumble, but I didn't use that feature.  I didn't use WaveBirds - I used an official Nintendo GCN controller.  But, as mentioned below, the adapter stopped working, so it was returned to the eBay seller.

Answer (score 1):

If it looks OK in the windows game controller control panel, Joy2Key is the issue.

Try using xPadder instead, it is far superior to Joy2Key. There is a free version linked in this question: [How can I emulate keyboard and mouse commands with a game controller?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13575)

Also if it's this adapter, it says something about changig the function of the stick by holding start and A for 3 seconds:
http://www.mayflash.com/Products/PCUSB/PC051.html

Comment: Sorry, I asked this question a while ago, and I wasn't expecting more answers.  The GCN to PC USB adapter was the PC051 model that you mentioned.  Believe it or not, it stopped working completely, to the point where the controller was no longer recognized in the Windows USB Controller setup.  So it has been returned to the original eBay seller in which it came.  Thanks for your help, though!  I will try xPadder for future controller hookups.

Answer (score 1):

I see an "emulation" tag in your question, if you're using the adapter in, for example dolphin, you don't need JoyToKey. That is, the controller should be recognized by any program that is able to recognize a common controller. JoyToKey is made for general control of the OS, and past versions of the tool had issues with right sticks. I believe newer versions fixed this.

Comment: The question is very old, and I did read the other answer, but aren't questions here supposed to help future readers besides the OP? If someone ever has the same issue, they might come over here, and wonder what's up with JoyToKey.

Comment: Yes, I was aware that the emulators could handle controllers on their own, but for consistency I wanted to use a program for all of them to avoid configuring the controller on each emulator.  That and because there is some software that doesn't directly support a USB joypad.